# Safe remedies for hoarse voice?

Tags: voice, health

What are the safe remedies to cure a hoarse voice? Are there any safety tips on how to handle the hoarse voice as quick as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some things you can do to make your voice happy:

1. Stop talking.  Don't sing.  Don't even whisper.  The more you let your vocal folds rest, the more quickly they will settle their inflammation.
2. Drink tea with honey - natural, organic honey is best.  Also, I personally like green tea but I think black or another favorite brand will work also.  As long as it is warm, the honey will do a nice job coating your throat.
3. Gargle warm / tepid salt water.  Mix it up, tilt the head back, let it go.  Don't make sound while you gargle.  People think you need to make sounds because of cartoons.  Really, all you need to do is exhale through your mouth.
4. Drink lots of water.  Water is always good.
5. Stop doing whatever was making your voice hoarse to begin with.  Hoarseness comes from inflammation of the vocal folds, which causes improper vibrations, thus resulting in impure vocal production (hoarseness).  For example, if you sing Screamo music, you can save your voice a lot of agony by simply turning up the input signal on the microphone to overload the microphone's diaphragm.

This list is not comprehensive but is a good start to get the ball rolling.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure how turning up the gain on a mike will overload its diaphragm. The diaphragm is what picks up the air vibrations. Gain occurs after that, not before.

Comment: @theTinMan - you are correct, my apologies. I meant "input signal." I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh. That makes a LOT more sense. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The natural remedy is to take a rest.  Lack of sleep may delay the natural healing process. Also, lack of water is another factor.

Added remedies are to take green and ginger teas.  It can help a lot.

This [article](http://voices.yahoo.com/how-cure-hoarse-voice-6757232.html) on Yahoo has also provided some help.